# DirectX9 (D3D) "Remap" SkinInfo after Progressive Mesh generation

Tags: c++, direct3d

I'm stuck for some days on generating a progressive skinned mesh, I have no problem with optimisation, but when the number of vertices change, there position in the vertexBuffer too and I cant find a solution to update the SkinInfo with the new positions, I tried that :

```
D3D::Mesh m;
meshData->pMesh->CloneMesh(D3DXMESH_MANAGED, Declaration, D3D::getDevice(), &m);
LPD3DXBUFFER vRemap=0;
D3D::checkError("Failed to optimise mesh",
    m->Optimize(D3DXMESH_MANAGED | D3DXMESHOPT_VERTEXCACHE | D3DXMESHOPT_ATTRSORT,
        newMeshContainer->pAdjacency,newMeshContainer->pAdjacency,
        0,&vRemap,&m));

if (pSkinInfo) {
    D3D::checkError("Failed to remap skin info",
        pSkinInfo->Remap( m->GetNumVertices(), 
        (DWORD*)vRemap->GetBufferPointer()));
}

D3DXCleanMesh(D3DXCLEAN_SIMPLIFICATION, m, newMeshContainer->pAdjacency, &m, newMeshContainer->pAdjacency, NULL);

D3D::ProgressiveMesh ProgMesh;
D3D::checkError("Failed to generate progressive mesh",
    D3DXGeneratePMesh(m, newMeshContainer->pAdjacency, 0, 0, 0, D3DXMESHSIMP_FACE, &ProgMesh));
ProgMesh->SetNumVertices(ProgMesh->GetMaxVertices());

ProgMesh->CloneMesh(D3DXMESH_MANAGED, 0, D3D::getDevice(), &newMeshContainer->MeshData.pMesh);
```

Someone knows any way to do it? I didn't found any information about it on internet, just some people saying thats done automaticly, but it doesn't work for me...

Sorry for my bad english...